# Entire function that equals sine

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> **Old exam exercise:**
>
> Let $f$, $g$ be entire and $f^2+g^2=1$. Prove that there is an entire function $H$ such that $f=\cos(H)$ and $g=\sin(H)$.

**My solution:**

(1): $f^2+g^2=(f+ig)(f-ig)=1$

We have $f+ig=\cos(H)+ i \sin(H) = e^{iH}$. So we can simply define: $i H(z) = \ln(f+ig)$, so $H(z) = -i \cdot \ln(f+ig)$, where $\ln$ is the main branch.

We need to know that this is well defined. But all we need for that is that $f+ig$ is never $0$, but that follows from (1).

---

Is this correct?

Comment: $f+ig$ is never zero (ok), and their domain is simply connected (I just think it's good to emphasize this fact). Also, while I nitpick presentation, in your first sentence you shouldn't say "We have $f+ig$=\cos H+i\sin H=e^{iH}." Rather, replace "we have" with something like "we want", because at this stage you still haven't defined $H$